# Were the VAX eXtended Function Control (XFC) instructions ever used commercially?

Tags: dec, microcode, vax

The DEC VAX has a set of 256 instructions set aside for user addition via microcode edits. Were extension sets ever commercially produced and sold, or was this functionality mostly used in-house?

Including links to documentation and software that uses the extension would be greatly appreciated, as well.

For documentation on this range of instructions, check the 1987 VAX Architecture Reference Manual, page 101 (115 in most scans)

Comment: Yea, sure, give me a minute. I have a copy of the VAX Architecture Handbook, but bitsavers doesn't keep scans of it. IIRC they're opcodes FC 00 through FC FF

Answer (score 13):

I was VAX Architect for six years in the late '80s, and at least during my tenure, Raytheon was the only company licensed to design VAX-compatible processors, for producing MIL-SPEC machines. They did design at least one (a high-performance processor with a very interesting microarchitecture that translated VAX instructions on the fly into a RISC-like internal form), and it could conceivably have used those opcodes, but I don't remember its having done so, and it seems unlikely since the purpose was to create a MIL-SPEC machine that could run standard software. Furthermore, I don't know that their processor design ever shipped. Raytheon and Norden did sell Digital's processor designs in hardened versions under the MILVAX name. The ICF Systime 8750 mentioned in Wikipedia (and which I'd never heard of before today) similarly appears to be a repackaged Digital design. It's possible that some customer might have used the FC opcodes to do software emulation of non-existent hardware instructions, but that would have few advantages over just calling the emulator. So the short answer is, probably no one ever used the FC opcodes.

Comment: Systime was a UK system vendor that built systems with DEC processors, other DEC parts, and some parts of their own or third parties.  When I was at university, I had friends who were making side income writing Basic-Plus programs under RSTS/E on Systime "PDP-11" systems.  I hadn't heard of Systime VAXen, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systime_Computers) says such existed.

Answer (score 5):

I microcoded up all the UNIX string functions, just to see if anything could be gained; and also a dynamic programming solution of an esoteric parsing problem.  The former would need huge strings to pay off, and the latter was a factor of ten speedup but too non-portable to be useful.

Any long procedure has to suspend itself often enough to allow interrupts, which otherwise wait for the microcode you write to finish, so there's that annoyance in coding in addition (stop and restart points in the microcode hand-coded in, which will involve memory writes and reads).

Answer (score 3):

- There was a user guide for the VAX-11/780 microprogramming tools with an example of how to create and invoke user-written microcode.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390036/vax-what-cpus-can-vax-simulate-with-microcode (although it has a broken link to the "VAX-11/780 Microprogramming Tools User's Guide")
- Here is one academic project: "No IBOX modifications were necessary other than the DRAM entries which are needed by the EBOX, since we use normal VAX addressing modes and the extended VAX opcodes (FD xy) to represent a WAM program." http://hps.ece.utexas.edu/pub/gee_micro19.pdf
- Here is another academic project: https://www.computer.org/csdl/magazine/mi/1983/06/04071007/13rRUxAASP5
- One could imagine it to be of interest to customers with applications which they did not publicly disclose, but I do not know of any.

Comment: here's a wayback link for the [VAX-11/780 Microprogramming Tools User's Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20190725113840/http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/vax/780/AA-H306B_780uprogToolsMar82.pdf) that works ...